# How use other project DLL in one solution in Visual studio 2015 RC

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, dependency-injection, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio 2015 RC. I have create two project(1st is Core(Class library) and 2nd is Web(C#)) in one solution.

I want to add Core.DLL in Web project. And in Web reference their two ref are available DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core 5.0. When i am adding this DLL in reference of Web then it goes in DNX 4.5.1 And when i am going to build Web project then got an error like: see attached image.

[image]

Please suggest me. How add Core.DLL in DNX Core 5.0. Or with out adding dll how access other project classes.

Awaiting for your response. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Jatin

Comment: Can you check to make sure the reference is in your `project.json` [file](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file)? Most of the properties for vNext projects were shifted to use the project.json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete `"dnxcore50": { }` from `project.json` if you dont use it. That should fix the problem.